# Extract dynamic url from rich text box VB.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, extract

I have a vb.net program where I have a extracted the source code into a richtext box.
I need help to extract a url from it.
Here's part of the richtextbox
http://pastebin.com/WgKjnE1r
What I need to extract is the 
http://www.myurl.com/?action=joingiveaway&id=287
But the number at the end changes
Is there an easy way to accomplish this?
I tried using regex but couldn't really get that to work
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Just the number changes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is just the number that changes then you can do it with this:

```
 http://www\.myurl\.com/\?action=joingiveaway&amp;id=([0-9]+)
```

[Regex101 Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vV4iG3)